# Windows installer for Java application from GitHub with drivers and automatic updates

Tags: java, windows, git, github, installation

I have a JavaFx application on GitHub that is easy to use for Linux experts: `git clone` it and execute the `run.sh` script that executes `java` and `javac` on the main class. If they want to update to the newest version they can just use `git pull` on the master branch.

However I noticed that Windows users are often less versed in those technologies so I want to create an all-in-one installer for them. Also, on Windows, one of a few possible drivers may have to be installed.

**I know that there are many Windows Java-installers available but I am looking for a specific feature set:**

- run even when Java is not already installed
- preferably (1) include its own Java distribution so that the user doesn't have to install it or alternatively (2) check if Java SDK version >= 8 is already installed and if not download and install it for the user. I prefer option 1 because I found that Java is sometimes installed but not correctly configured.
- ask the user where to install it, defaulting to Windows standards
- clone the application from the GitHub repository and move it to the user defined path
- compile the code
- give the user the option to install one of the drivers
- create a desktop link, start menu entry and uninstall entry
- give full access rights to hardware (as far as that is possible with Java)

When the user starts the application, it should do a `git pull` and, if necessary, recompile (ideally just the classes that changed).

Comment: Look at java webstart which can be set up to launch from a webpage.  I do not know if it is updated for JavaFX.  You should in any case use release versions to ensure stability!

Comment: @thorbjorn that requires Java to be installed and a browser with the right settings,  I think USB access will not be possible in the sandbox.

Comment: Last time I looked the deployment kit for JWS allowed Java detection initially in the browser and took you to the "Install Java"-page if none were detected.    Anyway, I would strongly recommend against your approach with doing things on the final system - you should build your application on a machine you know to be clean to ensure reproducibility when bugs are filed.

Comment: You can get out of the sandbox using signed code (which again require you to either share your key or build yourself).  The "access USB" requirement were not in your question and may be important - please revise to include all you need.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen You are right, I added this requirement to the question.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen OK I extended the requirement to give full hardware access to make the problem less specific.

Comment: I sincerely think you have chosen the wrong approach to implement this in.  Consider reconsidering.